# Buffer Overflow to change address that gets returned to

Tags: c, buffer, overflow, memory-address

I'm trying to call the `oopsIGotToTheBadFunction` by changing the return address via the user input in `goodFunctionUserInput`.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int oopsIGotToTheBadFunction(void)
{
    printf("Gotcha!\n");
    exit(0);
}

int goodFunctionUserInput(void)
{
    char buf[12];
    gets(buf);
    return(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    goodFunctionUserInput();
    printf("Overflow failed\n");
    return(1);
}


/**
> gcc  isThisGood.c

> a.out

hello

Overflow failed

*/
```

I've tried loading the buffer with 0123456789012345 but not sure what to put for the rest of it to get the address. The address is 0x1000008fc.

Any insights or comments would be helpful.

Comment: You're going to need to compile with `-fno-stack-protector` to keep stack cookies from stopping your efforts.  Also, you should *always* be compiling with `-Wall -Werror` to catch a bunch of stupid mistakes.

Comment: Maybe you should go read the originals, like [Smashing the stack for fun and profit](http://www.phrack.org/issues/49/14.html#article) by Aleph 1?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart IMO, the code was't compiled w/ stack protections, since I don't see the program was aborted

Comment: For every engineer who builds a railway, there will be someone who tries to derail a train, for his amusement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have taken a look at that file...but it didnt seem that helpful...though I could be missing something

Comment: If you really need help to break something, go find a gang to big you up.

Comment: Maybe you're not ready to be doing this exercise, then?  Or maybe it _is_ too old, now.  It is most of 20 years old, and there are lots of protections in place that weren't back then. However, it is one of the founding articles for what you're trying to do, namely smashing the stack.  There are lots of books and articles on how to go stack smashing — you should be able to find what you need online.

Comment: I apologise for my comments. This kind of request makes me so angry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm not 100% sure, but the OP is more interested in buffer overflow exploits than programs that are actually socially and/or professionally useful.

Comment: I apologize, this was for a homework assignment due last night and i was stuck and thought that maybe you guys could help me out

Comment: Homework?  For 'Malware 101'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give this the benefit of the doubt and presume this is an exercise intended to learn about the stack (perhaps homework) and not learning how to do anything malicious.

Consider where the return address of goodFunctionUserInput is on the stack and what would happen if you changed it. You may wish to check the disassembly to see how much space on the stack the compiler made for goodFunctionUserInput and where exactly buf is. When you figure out how long a string to enter, consider the endianness of the machine and what that means for the address you want to overwrite into the return address of goodFunctionUserInput. Worrying about what sorts of awful things this does to the stack isn't important here as your function you want to call simply calls exit.